# jBPM 6 how to define a swimlane to a task

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I'm having a problem with Tasks and Lanes, I need that the actor who fire tasks persists during all the life cycle with its own data, and others actors cannot claim this tasks.

In tasks properties there are no swimlanes definition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jBPM6, the task itself doesn't have a swimlane property anymore (as the Eclipse modeler in jBPM5 had), just use a graphical swimlane and put the task in it.

A second task in the swimlane should automatically be assigned to the person that completed the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The swimlane is a graphical process element, just like tasks, and you can find it in the Object library between Data objects and Artifacts in jBPM 6. There is no entry in the current documentation for swimlanes but there is a small entry for it in the documentation for RedHat's commercial version:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.0/html/User_Guide/Lanes.html